# XSLT for multiple conditions

Tags: xslt

I have a question on XSLT. Basically I am look for ...Unique Delivery method ( Mail,Home etc) from last transaction for books having status 'In Stock' from the below xml.  For example in the below example 'Mail' and 'Store Pickup' would be the result. Can somebody help me with XSLT ? Thanks in advance.

```
<BookCollection>
    <Book>
        <status>In Stock</status>
        <name>The Hunt for Red October</name>
        <OrderHistory>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>sssss</transactionid>
               <date>2018-03-24</date>
               <Delivery>Home</Delivery>
           </Order>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>sssss</transactionid>
              <date>2018-04-23</date>
              <Delivery>Mail</Delivery>
           </Order>
        </Orderhistory>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <name>A case of need</name>
        <status>Pending Stock</status>
        <OrderHistory>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>sssss</transactionid>
               <date>2018-08-24</date>
               <Delivery>Home</Delivery>
           </Order>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>sssss</transactionid>
              <date>2018-02-23</date>
              <Delivery>Store Pickup</Delivery>
           </Order>
        </Orderhistory>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <name>Sharp Objects</name>
        <status>In Stock</status>
        <OrderHistory>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>sssss</transactionid>
               <date>2018-01-24</date>
               <Delivery>Home</Delivery>
           </Order>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>sssss</transactionid>
              <date>2018-05-23</date>
              <Delivery>Store Pickup</Delivery>
           </Order>
        </Orderhistory>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <name>Happy Doomsday</name>
        <status>In Stock</status>
        <OrderHistory>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>aaa</transactionid>
               <date>2018-01-24</date>
               <Delivery>Mail</Delivery>
           </Order>
           <Order>
              <transactionid>bb</transactionid>
              <date>2018-03-23</date>
              <Delivery>Store Pickup</Delivery>
           </Order>
        </Orderhistory>
    </Book>
        .......
        .........
    </Book>
</BookCollection>
```

Comment: What does "last transaction" exactly mean, last `Order` element inside the `OrderHistory` child of a `Book`, or  `Order` elements ordered by the `date` and taking the `Order` with the latest `date`? Which version of XSLT do you use or can you use? What have you tried to solve the different tasks (selecting the `Book` elements, identifying distinct values)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into... last transaction means, recent transaction a transactoin was made on march 2018 and another on june 2018, I want June to be considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically if you want to find distinct items, you can view it as a grouping issue, but you only need to output one value from each group. In XSLT 1.0 you would use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), which would mean defining a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="Delivery" />
```

However, you have the added complexity of getting the last Order by date. Probably the easiest option is to create a variable holding only the last `Order` elements for each `OrderHistory`

```
  <xsl:variable name="Orders">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Book[status = 'In Stock']/OrderHistory">
      <xsl:for-each select="Order">
        <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />    
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>
```

However, you need to use an extension function to convert this "Result Tree Fragment" into a node-set which you can then use the Muencjian Grouping technique on. Most like your process support EXSLT, which means adding this namespace

```
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
```

Then, to get the distinct values from the variable, you do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($Orders)/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', Delivery)[1])]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="orders" match="Order" use="Delivery" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="Orders">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Book[status = 'In Stock']/OrderHistory">
      <xsl:for-each select="Order">
        <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <xsl:copy-of select="." />    
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($Orders)/Order[generate-id() = generate-id(key('orders', Delivery)[1])]">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="Delivery" />     
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See this in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtu/2 (which is using Microsoft's XSLTCompiledTransform, which is XSLT 1.0).

Ideally though, you should look into upgrading to XSLT 3.0, if only to stop Martin Honnen getting bored....

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with this Tim.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in pure XPath 3 if the higher-order version of the `sort` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-sort is supported:

```
distinct-values( 
    BookCollection/Book[status = 'In Stock'] 
    ! 
    sort(
      OrderHistory/Order, 
      (), 
      function($order) { xs:date($order/date) }
    )[last()]/Delivery
)
```

A complete XSLT 3 stylesheet that would work with Saxon 9.8 EE or PE or any other XSLT 3 processor supporting the higher-order function feature would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of 
            select="distinct-values( 
                        BookCollection/Book[status = 'In Stock'] ! sort(OrderHistory/Order, (), function($order) { xs:date($order/date) })[last()]/Delivery
                    )"
            separator=", "/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 3 processors like Saxon 9.8 HE where the higher-order variant of `sort` is not supported you need to delegate the sorting to your own function:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of 
        select="distinct-values( 
                    BookCollection/Book[status = 'In Stock'] ! mf:sort(OrderHistory/Order)[last()]/Delivery
                )"
        separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:function name="mf:sort" as="element(Order)*">
    <xsl:param name="orders" as="element(Order)*"/>
    <xsl:perform-sort select="$orders">
        <xsl:sort select="xs:date(date)"/>
    </xsl:perform-sort>
</xsl:function>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqs.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Is there a way with xslt 1.0 ? I am limited to using 1.0 only :(